# Fine Grained Access in DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

My users signup with facebook and table has basic user information. I want users to update, delete etc only their own records but also be able to ***have read access to attributes of all other users***. E.g. see their names. How do I create a policy that allows this ? This is for scenario no 1:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "FullAccessToUserItems",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/Users"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                      "${graph.facebook.com:id}"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another statement with read permissions to whole table.

Something like this should work:

```
{
    "Sid": "ReadAccess",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
        "dynamodb:Query"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/Users"
    ]
}
```

And the whole policy would be like this. Notice second statement at the bottom:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "FullAccessToUserItems",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/Users"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                      "${graph.facebook.com:id}"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ReadAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:Query"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/Users"
        ]
    }
]
}
```